# Changing requestAlwaysAuthorization to requestWhenInUseAuthorization not working

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

My app used to use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` with an Info.plist entry for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

I changed it to use a `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` with an Info.plist entry for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

After the change the app can no longer get the location. It only receives a `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` of `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. The OS does not prompt for a change in permission (which makes sense because it already has permission for always. The settings menu for the app does not contain an entry for location information (which would allow me to revoke or approve it). `didFailWithError` is never called.

I then switched back to using `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` with an Info.plist entry for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and restarted the app. The OS prompts for a change in permission to always. I grant it and the location starts working perfectly.

Deleting the app before reinstalling it has no effect.

I am using IOS 9.2. This happens on a real iPhone and on the simulator. I have the simulator's location set to Apple.

Comment: Did you change the permission requesting call ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes. As I wrote I changed it the app to call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location Manager can be a real hit or miss on the simulator, for me at least, sometimes it works well and sometimes it doesn't. Have you tried running it on a device?

Comment: Yes I have tried. The same exact thing happens on a simulator.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant the exact same thing happens on a real iphone as on a simulator.